# How can I change the home directory of some code?

Tags: php

I found some PHP online (it's a 1 page file manager with no permissions) that I find is really awesome, it suits my current needs. However, I'm having some issues changing the working (default) directory.

I got the script from a GitHub project that is no longer maintained. The PHP itself is a 1 page PHP file manager with no permissions, no databases etc. I already have a user accounts system and would like to change the working directory based on an existing database variable, however I can't seem to find a way around changing the directory.

Currently, the script is uploaded to `/home/advenacm/public_html/my/` (as the file is `/home/advenacm/public_html/my/files.php`. By what I can tell, the PHP uses a cookie to determine the working directory, but it can't find a way around setting a custom directory. I want to use `'/home/advenacm/public_html/my/'.$userdomain;`, which will as a result become something like `/home/advenacm/public_html/my/userdomain.com/`.

What I would like to do is set the default (or "home") directory so that the file manager cannot access the root directory, only a specified subfolder.

Something like `directory = "/home/advenaio/public_html/directory/"` is the best way to explain it. I've tried a number of methods to try and achieve this but nothing seems to work.

I've taken the liberty of uploading my code to [**pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/VcdnbvjM) with the PHP syntax highlighting. Here is the snippet of PHP that I believe is choosing the working directory (line 19-29):

```
$tmp = realpath($_REQUEST['file']);
if($tmp === false)
    err(404,'File or Directory Not Found');
if(substr($tmp, 0,strlen(__DIR__)) !== __DIR__)
  err(403,"Forbidden");
if(!$_COOKIE['_sfm_xsrf'])
    setcookie('_sfm_xsrf',bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)));
if($_POST) {
    if($_COOKIE['_sfm_xsrf'] !== $_POST['xsrf'] || !$_POST['xsrf'])
        err(403,"XSRF Failure");
}
```

I appreciate any help anyone can offer me and would like to thank anyone in advance for even taking the time to look at my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [chdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)  function ?

**later edit**
Updating my answer based on your edited question.

The main problem is line 30

```
$file = $_REQUEST['file'] ?: '.';
```

That needs to be a full real path to the file and has to be compared with your user's 'home'.
And you should use the same path for the checks at line 19.
So you can replace 19-30 with:

```
$user_home = __DIR__ . "/{$userdomain}";

$file = $_REQUEST['file'] ?: $user_home; //you might have to prepend $userdomain to $_REQUEST['file'], can't see from html the format.
$file = realpath($_REQUEST['file']);

if($file === false) {
    err(404,'File or Directory Not Found');
}

if(strpos($file, $user_home) !== 0) {
    err(403,"Forbidden");
}

if(!$_COOKIE['_sfm_xsrf']) {
    setcookie('_sfm_xsrf',bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)));
}

if($_POST) {
    if($_COOKIE['_sfm_xsrf'] !== $_POST['xsrf'] || !$_POST['xsrf'])
        err(403,"XSRF Failure");
}
```

Although this might solve your question I think the entire script is a poorly written solution.

Comment: check the return of chdir(), if it's `false` then it didn't work, if it's true then the problem is not with changing directory

Comment: It was `true`.. Not sure what to do now

Comment: for a starter you can edit your question and clarify what you are trying to do, nobody will read that papyrus you've pastebined :)

Comment: I've done that.. I hope I've made things easier for you :)

Comment: Debug it a bit, see what's in `$file` and what's in `$home_user`. I don't know what's in `$_REQUEST['file']` or how you determine `$userdomain`